# Sass function simple example is giving error

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have the following sass code which is giving error. Please help!

**main.scss**

```
@function alpha($background, $color, $font-size){
    return {
    background: $background,
    color: $color,
    font-size: $font-size
    }
}

div {alpha(yellow, violet, 24);}
p {alpha(blue, orange, 20);}
```

**Error:**

fatal error: parse error: failed at `background: $background,` (stdin) on line 3

> **Note:** I know this can be done my Mixin. But, what I read is that
>   Mixins & Functions can be used inter-changably. So, I want to do this
>   work by Functions only (to see if they are really do all work of
>   mixins).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing [`mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin)s and [`function`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function)s here.

Mixins provide for (nested) rules and values while function only return values.

What you need is a mixin like here

```
@mixin alpha($background, $color, $font-size) {
   background: $background;
   color: $color;
   font-size: $font-size;
}

div {@include alpha(yellow, violet, 24);}
p {@include alpha(blue, orange, 20);}
```

## Explanation

#### This is how you use Mixins

```
@mixin red-align($text-align: left) {
   color: red;
   text-align: $text-align
}


body h1 {
  @include red-align(center);
}
```

#### This is how you use Functions

```
@function red($opacity: 1) {
   @return rgba(255, 0, 0, $opacity);
}
@function align($text-align: left) {
   @return $text-align;
}

body h1 {
  color: red();
  text-align: align(center);
}
```

Both examples yield:

```css
body h1 {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but I think functions can do all the work of mixins also, so I was trying to do the same by functions.

Comment: @Deadpool No. Functions only deliver values, no rules or selectors